# PDF files are not shown in website but working fine in localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read my "pdf files" in PHPMYSQL tables. So I found the script from some forums and it's work fine in "localhost using XAMPP".
But When I deploy to website, it's not showing pdf files and all information after that line are missing.
I dont know what is the problem. Kindly someone can help me please...

```
<div class="page-title">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="articles">Journals</a></li>
          <li><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">

                <div class="single-post">

                    <div class="post-title-area">
                        <a class="post-cat" href="<?php echo $post_cat_link; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></a>
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            <?php echo $title; ?>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="post-meta">
                            <span class="post-date"><i class="feather icon-clock"></i> <?php echo $post_date; ?></span>
                            <span class="post-comment"><i class="feather icon-eye"></i>
                            <span><?php echo $post_views; ?></span></span>
                        </div>
                        
                <div class="div1">
                
                <?php echo "View PDF File for Journal Details" ?>
                <?php
                
                    mysql_connect('localhost','adminjournal','adminjournalikat');
                    mysql_select_db('journal');

                    //  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
                    // mysql_select_db('journal');
                
                $sql="SELECT pdf from tbl_blog_posts";
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while ($info=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?>
                <embed type="application/pdf" src="pdf/<?php echo $info['pdf'] ; ?>" width="900" height="500">
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content-area">
                        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
            if ($yt_vid == "") {
              ?>
              <div class="post-media post-featured-image">
              <img src="images/blog/<?php echo $media; ?>" class="img-fluid single_blog" alt="">
              </div>
              <?php
            }else{
              ?>
              <div class="post-media post-video">
                <div class="embed-responsive">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $yt_vid; ?>"></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
           
            <?php echo $cont?>
            <br></br>
            
          </div>
                    <div class="tags-area clearfix">
                            <div class="post-tags">
                                <span>Tags:</span>
              <?php
              $post_tags = explode(",",$tags);
              foreach ($post_tags as $tag) {

                if (WBCleanURL == "true") {
                  $st1 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", " ", $tag);
                  $st2 =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $st1);
                  $tag_title = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $st2));

                  $tag_link = "tags/$tag_title";
                }else{
                  $tag_link = "pages/tags?key=$tag_title";
                }

              ?><a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>"><?php echo $tag; ?></a><?php
              }
              ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        
    
                        <div class="share-items clearfix">
                        <ul class="post-social-icons unstyled">
                            <li class="facebook">
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $sharelink; ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span class="ts-social-title">Facebook</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="twitter">
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $sharelink; ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <span class="ts-social-title">Twitter</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="gplus">
                                <a href="mailto:info@example.com?&subject=&cc=&bcc=&body=<?php echo $sharelink; ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span class="ts-social-title">Email</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please have all pictures etc. here, not in 3rd party sites. Don't copy-paste the same text into your question multiple times.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for your advise. I'm sorry since this is the first time for me. Btw, How to put a pictures in here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi K J, thanks for your reponse... I can't paste the picture, but I re-post more script. Hopefully easier to see what is the cause of thsi issue... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your clue that this issue because of overlapping. Finally I found out the script problem... below is the right one...
Thanks a lot and Wish You All The Best

```
 <?php echo $cont?>
            <br></br>
            
            <?php echo "PDF File Details for Journal" ?>    
              <br><h4><a href="https://journal.ikatbatam.com/pdf/<?php echo $pdf;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title;?> </a></h4>
```